# Dual TabBars in StoryBoard IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I've seen that there isn't any possibility of adding a custom tab bar in `TabBarController` in `StoryBoard` of `IOS`. However a single tabBar can contains multiple buttons. But I want to design two tab bars (first one on top and second one on bottom of storyboard) and the content I want to see in the middle of both tabBars. How can I design my custom tabBars using storyboard?
I'm currently designed in `xib` but I want to get rid of the `xib` and have to design an `autolayout` tab bars on storyboard and to avoid remove sub views again and again when each button is called.

Is it possible to design dual tabbars in storyboard?

Comment: What do you mean by, "first one on top and second one on bottom of storyboard" -- do you mean you want them in the same controller's view? Do you want them both visible at the same time when you run? Are you using a tab bar controller, or adding these to a UIViewController?

Comment: Yeah, on same view Controller, and im using tab bar controller, in storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 tab bar controllers at the same time. The tab bar controller won't allow it, and Apple would very likely reject your app if you created that look yourself. It sounds like a really bad user interface, frankly.

That said, if you want to create an UI with a normal tab bar on the bottom of the window and another thing that looks and acts like a tab bar at the top, you could create a custom parent view controller class and implement your "top tab bar" look yourself, then use that custom view controller as one of the tabs in your tab bar controller. However, I'd bet money that Apple would reject such a thing as a violation of the HIG (Human Interface Guidelines).

Comment: Thankyou very much, I've to change my UI as per ur suggestions. By the way, can u please send me the exact documentation reference of tab bar guidelines. Thanks once again.

Comment: Search in the Xcode docs for the string "A tab bar gives people the ability to switch between different subtasks, views, or modes in an app". Then look for the search result that is from the iOS HIG.

Comment: The right way to do it would be to program your own Container View Controller, which Apple documentation explains what you'd have to implement / etc. Definitely not (easily or conventionally) done using storyboard. I think there's probably a better interface for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @sammoore, that's what I meant by parent view controller in my answer. Container view controller is a better term though.